# How to set timeout for each message JmsListener receives?

Tags: jms, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I have a Spring `JmsListener` which receives messages from an SQS queue.

Now I need to set processing_timeout for each message I receive.

Lets assume that I have set processing_timeout to 2 mins, then each message received by `Jmslistener` should finish before 2 mins. If not, an exception should be thrown (which will make the SQS to resend immediately).

How do I set this processing_timeout for each message?

Answer (score 0):

Without going into the guts of spring-jms, the only way I can see would be for your `@JmsListener` to launch a worker thread, that it could time and chop.